# How to refer SqlDataSource to GridView control, when SqlDataSource is created in code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

In the aspx page I have:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
```

In the code-behind page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM my_table_name";
    this.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
}
```

Which throws a server error:

> The DataSourceID of '`GridView1`' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID '`SqlDataSource1`' could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove data source id from aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

do it from code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
    .AppSettings["MyConnectionString"];
    SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM my_table_name";
    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought naming the sqlDataSource is equal to setting its ID, it's not. I have to explicitly set `SqlDataSource.ID = "SqlDataSource";`